# Rails, user input persist when showing activerecord error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Currently, I have text fields and some validation on the model. However, when I show the error message, all the data that was inserted by the user will be gone. I want to show the error message + the data to persist. Here is the code:

```
<% if @student.errors.any? %>
        <div id="validation_error" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <ul>
                <% @student.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
<% end %>
<%= form_for(:user_student, :url => {:controller => 'profile', :action => 'information'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :first_name, :value => @student.first_name, class: "form-control" , :placeholder => "First Name"  %>
<%= f.text_field :last_name, :value => @student.last_name, class: "form-control" , :placeholder => "Last Name"  %>
<% end %>

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :first_name, :presence => true
    validates :last_name, :presence => true
end
```

**UPDATED**
Controller:

```
def information
    @student = Student.create(check_new_student_params)
    if @student.save
       #redirect to other page
    end
end

def check_new_student_params
    params.require(:user_student).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
end
```

My expected behaviour: when the user give first name but not last name, it will show the error message and the first name persist on the text field. Thanks

Comment: Can you show your controller code where you run the validation?

Comment: There is nothing much on the controller, the validation is mainly from the model

Comment: Can you add your controller so we can see the information action that is being called. This will be where the problem lies.

Comment: My only thought is that your controller might not be populating the @student object properly. Otherwise the information should persist when you render back the 'new' page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where your problem is. Your trying to create the object rather than assigning and trying to save. Upon save failing, you should render the page again

```
def information
    @student = Student.new(check_new_student_params)
    if @student.save
       #redirect to other page
    else
      render original page again
    end
end

def check_new_student_params
    params.require(:user_student).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a route to a s`new`

you should do this

```
def information
    @student = Student.new(check_new_student_params)
    if @student.save
       #redirect to other page
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

you're not telling rails to bring back the form after errors. and of course, you should have a `new` action in your controller.